# Search results with Sphinx and PHP by partial string

Tags: php, full-text-search, sphinx

I am try to getting started with Sphinx. I add some results to index, download `sphinxapi.php`, and when I do this:

```
$cl = new SphinxClient();
$cl->SetServer( "localhost", 9312 );
// SPH_MATCH_ALL will match all words in the search term
$cl->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_ALL);
$result = $cl->Query("test");
```

I getting this (row with `id = 5` where `title = test`):

```
array (size=1)
  5 =>  // id of post in database
array (size=2)
  'weight' => string '2' (length=1)
  'attrs' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
```

But why I didnt get row from database with `id = 6`, where `title` field equal to `test1` ?

And `$cl->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_ALL);` fire error:

```
DEPRECATED: Do not call this method or, even better, use SphinxQL instead of an API
```

I comment this line in code of api file:

```
trigger_error ( 'DEPRECATED: Do not call this method or, even better, use SphinxQL instead of an API', E_USER_DEPRECATED );
```

But I dont know if it fine. Can somebody help me to understand what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get 'substring' matches, you need to specifically enable them.

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-min-prefix-len

(or min_infix_len)

If you dont want to see the depreciated notice, then set error_reporting
http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

(but even better is to rewrite the code to avoid calling the depreciated method)

Comment: Hello, I configured `min_postfix_len`, `min_infix_len`, and `enable_star`, then when I run search in console I get any resylts only when using stars, but when place just part of string getting nothing...

Answer (score 1):

**warning setmatchmode**

SetMatchMode are deprecated, you can still use it but it can be removed in next versions.

More info about it in:

- http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#api-func-setmatchmode
- http://sphinxsearch.com/blog/2013/09/11/deprecations-and-changes-in-the-2-2-series/

extracted from sphinx forum (barryhunter):

> Changing the 'match mode' actually did TWO things, it changed the matching >behaviour - by
>   rewriting the query itself. AND changing the ranking mode.
>
> By decoupling these concepts, I guess the idea is reduce confusion.
>
> (for example, as soon as you choose a different matching mode, you can't >actully choose a
>   ranking mode)
>
> ... the match modes made sence before the 'extended syntax' was fully       developed, but now
>   everything can be done directly via the extended syntax.

**about search results**

barryhunter answer is right

I suggest to read more about charset tables, morphology and stemming because i think are a better way to achieve success search than wilcard searches.

- http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-charset-table
- http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-morphology